# python - finding Equilibriums in an array - error

Tags: python

I am trying to solve the equlibrium problem presented in Codility. I wrote a solution (probably not the most efficient one, but this is just for exercise purposes). The solution works on my PC but returns an error in the Codility environment. How this is possible? Where am I making a mistake?

[The problem](http://blog.codility.com/2011/03/solutions-for-task-equi.html) 
To find the equilibrium index of a sequence such that the sum of elements at lower indexes is equal to the sum of elements at higher indexes.

My Solution

```
A=[-1, 3, -4, 5, 1, -6, 2, 1]

def solution(A):

    results=[]
    n=len(A)
    P = [0] * (n)
    P[0] = A[0]
    for k in xrange(1, n):
        P[k] = P[k - 1] + A[k]


    for p in xrange(1,n):
        if P[p-1]==P[n-1]-P[p-1]-A[p]:
            results.append(p)


    if len(results) <> 0:
        return results
    else:
        return -1
```

> Compilation successful. Example test:    [-1, 3, -4, 5, 1, -6, 2, 1] 
>   Output (stderr): Invalid result type, int expected, 
>   found. RUNTIME ERROR  (tested program terminated unexpectedly)

Comment: You are to return the index of the first or any equilibrium value in the array. While you're returning list in `results`.

Comment: No.. For example `A = [-1, 3, -4, 5, 1, -6, 2, 1]`, `3` is an equilibrium value. You need to return the index of `3`, which is `1`. Since `A[1] is 3`.

Comment: @ choz something like 3, 5, 1  or  [3, 5, 1]?

Comment: @ choz  my code is returning the positions indexes [1,3,7]

Comment: Just return either 1, 3 or 7 would suffice. Go for jadsq's answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are supposed to return an integer in all cases, while your code returns a list in some cases and -1 in some other.

I think you may just return the fist result as the algorithm description doesn't seem to consider cases where solution isn't unique. So `return results[0]` instead of `return results` might fix it.

Comment: `results[0]` containing the value.. He is to return the index of that value in original list, not the value.

Comment: @choz `results[0]` isn't containing a value, it is contaning an index `p` in range 1 to `len(A)`. Maybe you're confusing lowercase `p` and uppercase `P` ?

Comment: @ jadsq  the code returns the proper answer on my PC, [1,3,7], it is very confusing, which is "results" array created using the small p

Comment: @Chris The problem that appears in the error is that you should not return a list [1,3,7] but only **one number**. Note that I am not sure if 1,3 or 7 are all correct answers but **even if they are then you should still only return one number** as this the expected output format .

Comment: ^ As he said @Chris. And also, I believe your solution might fail on certain test.. you should return the index immediately once you find the first index. Stop iterating the list once you find the result.

Comment: I replaced    #results.append(A[p]  with  return A[p]  and it works, returns a number and a solution is accepted, but the score is below the scale

Comment: @Chris You want to return `p` (the index) , not `A[p]` (the value at index p)

Comment: @  jadsq, that's right, just p. Too many times changed the code. Thanks